# some kotlin libraries attached to this project were compiled with a newer kotlin compiler and can't be read. Please update Kotlin plugin

Tags: android, kotlin

## some kotlin libraries attached to this project were compiled with a newer kotlin compiler and can't be read. Please update Kotlin plugin.

Addded this in build.gradle

```
 buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.1' // <= expected version is 1.5.1
}
```

Comment: You can find information about kotlin version here https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details
You have to use the latest one.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.